# Why does printing a module make the code function?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I was working with this code. Until I included print tweepy in the code the page on GAE returned as blank; no error, or anything. It worked fine from the command line. Why would this happen? Is there a better way to make this work?

```
import tweepy
print tweepy

CONSUMER_KEY = "mine"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "mine"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)

try:
    print auth.get_authorization_url()
except Exception,e: print str(e)
```

Comment: Maybe GAE had loaded an older version of the file, and for some reason had not noticed that the file had changed until you re-saved the file with the `print tweepy` change?

Comment: I've tried going back and forth removing/adding the print command multiple times; I don't think its a save issue.

Comment: They have some examples on the git hub can't see any trick to get it to work: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/tree/master/examples